# QT5 Fancy Browser not rendering Few pages that shows on regular chrome browser

Tags: qt5, qtwebkit

Im a noob with qt5 and fancy browser, there are a few pages that are not rendering on the fancy browser which is on the client SOC.

are there any tools i can use to debug why some pages are not rendering and some are.

i have enable the QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled, and is able to inspect the site and found the error. but the site runs seemlessly on a desktop environment

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: An example of a web page the QT fails to render would make answering the question much easier.